# PIL attribute error: Shape when creating an array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to warp two images of different sizes using PIL; specifically, by setting the shape (size) for future warped target image as a numpy array and I'm encountering AttributeError:

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 632, in **getattr**
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: shape

Why does this happen? I'm under the impression that I was doing this exact thing some time ago and it was working just fine, not to mention the fact that I absolutely don't understand what is it that python doesn't understand (the shape attribute should take this as an input with no problem)

```
import skimage.io
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np


Img1 = Image.open(picture1 + ".png") 
Img1

Img2 = Image.open(picture2 + ".png")
Img2

r, c = Img2.shape[:2]

    # creates array for the future shape in x,y
corners = np.array([[0, 0],
                    [0, r],
                    [c, 0],
                    [c, r]])
...
```

Regards, JJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Image objects have *size* attributes and arrays have *shape* attributes. Try renaming it in your code.
(See : http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm)